# Python Flask SocketIO - 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, streaming

I am trying to stream the response from SocketIO with Python Flask.

I am facing an error:
*TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, list, tuple with headers or status, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a function.*

```
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/test", methods=["POST"])
def test():
    def stream(socketio):
        print('stream function executed')
        dummy_response = "This is a dummy response."  # Replace with your desired dummy response

        for _ in range(5):  # Send the dummy response 5 times
            socketio.emit('answer', {'answer': dummy_response}) 
            


    threading.Thread(target=stream, args=(socketio)).start()

    return jsonify({"message": "Question received"})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, port=3000)
```

The separate script, which opens socket is:

```
import subprocess
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    print('Connected to the WebSocket server')

@sio.on('stream_response')
def handle_stream_response(data):
    print('Received response:', data)

sio.connect('http://localhost:3000')
sio.wait()

# Send POST request to the endpoint using curl
subprocess.Popen(['curl', '--http1.1', '-X', 'POST',
                  '-F,'http://localhost:3000/test'])
```

So for now I am just wanting to pass dummy string, to fix the error, than I will implement the real functionality.

For now I just want to enable streaming the response.